# Save Data of previous layout on orientation change while implementing onConfigChange()

Tags: android

If the user is putting data in edittext fields and orientation get changed, the onConfigChange method is called and new layout is populated,with empty edittext fields, i want to retain the data in edittext fields entered by user befor orientation change. 
Any kind of help will highly appreciated.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int orientation_default = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            switch (orientation_default) {
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT: {
                setContentView(R.layout.registration);

                break;
            }
            case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE: {
                setContentView(R.layout.registration_horizontal);
                break;
            }

            }
            findViewById(R.id.backtohomepage).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.backtologinpage).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.btn_notregyetsubmit).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.termsandconditions_id).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.btn_notregyetsubmit).setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setContentView(R.layout.registration);
                findViewById(R.id.termsandconditions_id).setOnClickListener(this);
                findViewById(R.id.backtohomepage).setOnClickListener(this);
                findViewById(R.id.backtologinpage).setOnClickListener(this);
            } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                setContentView(R.layout.registration_horizontal);
            }

            findViewById(R.id.backtologinpage).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.btn_notregyetsubmit).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.termsandconditions_id).setOnClickListener(this);
            findViewById(R.id.btn_notregyetsubmit).setOnClickListener(this);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Put android:configChanges="orientation" for that activity node in the manifest.

EDIT:
Check this question : [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
            android:name="com.Dashboard"
             android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            >
        </activity>
```

paste this in your manifest...
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html .. go through this link..